# Monogame vs ANX

Tags: windows-8, xna, monogame

I am looking for a Win8-Metro-friendly framework for my next game project. Two of the non-commercial options are Monogame and ANX. Both are XNA like. I am wondering which one is more mature and reliable?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 7):

MonoGame is coming up to version 3.0 stable release while ANX is in alpha at version o.4.x.
MonoGame is trying to be XNA 4.0 API compatible.
Microsoft evangelists are promoting MonoGame as a viable alternative to getting your XNA games onto the Windows 8 Store.
MonoGame has over several games already on the Windows 8 store that have passed approval and  games released on iOS, Android, MacOS, Linux and soon PlayStation Vita.

I cannot comment on ANX, as I've never used it, but if it surpasses everything I've mentioned above, use it.

Comment: The head developer of ANX itself recommended Monogame recently in a German XNA forum so I guess ANX won't be developed further

Comment: Why would you assume ANX won't be developed further? You can view recent commits here: http://anxframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets